# Como reescrever a URL do meu site?

Tags: nginx

Eu tenho a seguinte URL:

> http://exemplo.com/iframe/usuario/estacao

Preciso que o **nginx** faça uma "virada" para que o *usuário* e a *estacão* sejam passados como parâmetros para minha aplicação, assim:

> http://exemplo.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?user=usuario&workstation=estacao

---

Por exemplo, o cliente digita protocolo

> http://exemplo.com/iframe/francisco/parana

e o *app* vai receber protocolo:

> http://exemplo.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?user=francisco&workstation=parana

Comment: Favor traduzir sua pergunta. Este é o stackoverflow em Português.

Comment: reescreve essa url para o SO inglês :)

Comment: traduzido agora pessoal.. aguardadno resposta.. @AndréRibeiro

Comment: @mesaque Bom dia, o que você já tentou?

Comment: Amigo, sua pergunta está muito confusa. O que _exatamente_ você quer fazer?